# janitor package installed manually gives a strange error

Tags: r, installation, janitor

Due to an internet connection issue on some server (windows), I tried to manually install the `janitor` package after transferring a zipped version to the server.

I used the command:

```
install.packages("janitor.zip", lib = the folder with all the libraries, repos = NULL)
```

R lets me know the package was "successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked", however when trying to the function `clean_names` in the following way

```
clean_names(data.frame(x.1=1:10))
```

I get the following error:

```
number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)
```

The `janitor` is version 1.2.0, the R version is 3.5.2

`traceback` gives the following output:

```
9. step(e)
8. value[[3L]](cond)
7. tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]]
6. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
5. tryCatch(loadNamespace(name), error = function(e) stop(e))
4. getNamespace(ns)
3. asNamespace(ns)
2. getExportedValue(pkg, name)
1. janitor::clean_names
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How are you calling it to create that error? Which function?

Comment: `clean_names`... sorry I didn't mention that

Comment: What are you calling it with? Does `clean_names(data.frame(x.1=1:10))` fail?

Comment: Im calling it in several ways. after read_csv, I call it on the data_frame. I also use the shortcut read_csv("...csv") %>% janitor::clean_names(). Gives the same error in both cases.

Comment: None of what you've said is anything we can reproduce. Does my little example above also fail? Because that's about as simple as it gets. If that fails then something is broken. If that works but your usage fails, it could be a problem with your usage, we don't know unless we know precisely what you are using on it. please edit your question with examples.

Comment: the example you gave gives the same error. What do you mean by "something is broken"?

Comment: If the simplest possible example of a function fails (and I think my one-liner is just about that) then your installation of `janitor` is broken, possibly because you've not got all the correct versions of its dependencies. Edit your question, include **my** minimal example, show the error message, and the output from `traceback()` after the error, as well as the version number of `janitor` and its dependencies (and the version of R).

Comment: @Spacedman see edits above. Thanks!